# Issue with using Stubber with aibotocore in Pytest

Tags: python, asynchronous, pytest, botocore, pytest-asyncio

I have the below fixture that creates a mock aibotocore client and activates the botocore stubber on this, this works as expected with my pytest below.

```
import io
from contextlib import closing
import pytest
from aiobotocore.response import StreamingBody
from aiobotocore.session import get_session
from botocore.stub import ANY, Stubber
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager

@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
@asynccontextmanager
async def mock_client():
    with open("data.json", mode="rb") as f:
        encoded_message = f.read()
        body = AsyncBytesIO(encoded_message) #async version of io.BytesIO
        raw_stream = StreamingBody(body, len(encoded_message))

    response = {"Body": raw_stream}

    expected_params = {"Bucket": ANY, "Key": ANY}

    async with get_session().create_client(
        "s3", endpoint_url=endpoint
    ) as mock_client:
        stubber = Stubber(mock_client)
        stubber.add_response("get_object", response, expected_params)
        stubber.activate()
        yield mock_client

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_func(mock_client):
    with patch(
        "x.x.x.client" #refers to the aibotocore client
    ) as mock:
        mock.return_value = mock_client
        await func_under_test() #this method has the actual AWS S3 calls
        assert XXX
```

But now, I want to decouple the client and the stubber as I have a bunch of cases to test with various stubber responses. When I try to remove the stubber and place it inside the pytest, I get below errors -

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_func(mock_client):
    with patch(
        "x.x.x.client" #refers to the aibotocore client
    ) as mock:
        stubber = Stubber(mock_client)
        stubber.add_response("get_object", response, expected_params)
        stubber.activate()
        mock.return_value = mock_client
        await func_under_test() #this method has the actual AWS S3 calls
        assert XXX

>       operation_name = self.client.meta.method_to_api_mapping.get(method)
E       AttributeError: '_AsyncGeneratorContextManager' object has no attribute 'meta'
```

How can I make this work? I understand that fixture yields a '_AsyncGeneratorContextManager' object and if that's the case how are the tests working with the previous setup which also yields the same? If I remove the asynccontextmanager piece in total, I get the below errors -
'coroutine' object does not support the asynchronous context manager protocol
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'mock_client' was never awaited